# Couldn't find a ICreatesObservableForProperty for

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I have just started exploring ReactiveUI, but have some problems.

In a ReactiveObject, I try to make an observable based on a property...

```
public class StudentListViewModel : ReactiveObject, IStudentListViewModel
{
    public StudentListViewModel()
    {
        var observable = this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SearchQuery);
    }

    string _SearchQuery;
    public string SearchQuery
    {
        get { return _SearchQuery; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.SearchQuery, value); }
    }
}
```

...which leads to the following error:

> Couldn't find a ICreatesObservableForProperty for
>   MyApplication.ViewModels.StudentListViewModel. This should never
>   happen, your service locator is probably broken.

I have used `Ninject` as DI container, and tried to tell ReactiveUI about it like this:

```
class Bootstrapper : IBootstrapper
{
    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Kernel = new StandardKernel();
        Kernel.Bind<IBootstrapper>().ToConstant(this);
        Kernel.Bind<IScreen>().ToConstant(this);
        Kernel.Bind<IViewFor<StudentListViewModel>>().To<StudentListView>();

        Router = new RoutingState();

        RxApp.ConfigureServiceLocator(
            (type, key) => Kernel.Get(type, key),
            (type, key) => Kernel.GetAll(type, key),
            (from, type, key) =>
                {
                    var binding = Kernel.Bind(from).To(type);
                    if (key != null)
                        binding.Named(key);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Does anyone see the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched the 'from' and 'key':

```
    RxApp.ConfigureServiceLocator(
        (type, key) => Kernel.Get(type, key),
        (type, key) => Kernel.GetAll(type, key),
        (from, type, key) =>
            {
                var binding = Kernel.Bind(type /*this was from*/).To(from /*ditto*/);
                if (key != null)
                    binding.Named(key);
            }
        );
```

Comment: It's too easy to do, I need to make a way so that it's more obvious when this mistake happens